# Assync Task freezing UI

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm using an AsyncTask to download a file. But while it downloads the file, the UI gets freeze, and I have to wait the file to finish downloading to be able to do something. I've looked other threads, but I only found problems like running the task using `.get()`.
Here's how I'm calling the AsyncTask

```
new DownloadFileFromUrl().execute("url");
```

and here's the AsyncTask

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, LineData> {

    String fileDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/data.txt";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected LineData doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        //Download file--------------------------
        try {
            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileDir);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress((int) total * 100 / lenghtOfFile);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(LineData data) {
        setDataFor24Hours();
        setDataFor48Hours();
        setDataFor72Hours();
        showDataFor24Hours();
        setList();
        Log.e("Downloader: ", "done!");
    }

}
```

I've made it to send `Done!` to the monitor when it finishes, and at this moment the UI gets unfreeze also, so the problem is in the AsyncTask.
I hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does *frozen UI* mean, it is not taking user clicks?

Comment: Long-running operations should not really use an AsyncTask for several reasons like its dependence on the hosting Activity or Fragment. You should try a service that runs in the background and independent from the Activity or Fragment

Comment: Your result type is defined to be `LineData` but why are you returning `null` from `doInBackground()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask design in such a way that we can perform an action without freezing UI.
But `doInBackground`is only run in the background. But `onPostExecute` run on UI thread. So maybe your problem is in onPostExecute

Comment: Moved `Done!` to the end of the download function. You are right. The problem is in `onPostExecute()`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to define like this.

```
new DownloadFileFromUrl().execute("url");
```

Comment: Sorry, that's an error. I typed wrong here. Thanks anyway.